# Boolean Shared Preference is not storing

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am working on an Android game, in which in settings there is an option to turn off/on the sound of game.
I want to store these settings for the game, for this i am using shared preference to store a boolean value.
but issue is Boolean variable is not saving after app is closed.
here is my Code

Button Click Listener which is setting the `SharedPreference`

```
volume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (check == false) {
                check = true;
                PrefrencesClass.setBoolPreference(mContext,
                        Constants.APPSPREF, Constants.FIRSTTIME, true);
                volume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mute);
                Log.e("Check is True", "Preference is True");
            } else if (check == true) {
                check = false;
                volume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume);

                PrefrencesClass.setBoolPreference(mContext,
                        Constants.APPSPREF,Constants.FIRSTTIME, false);
                Log.e("Check is false", "Preference is false");
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volume is Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

My function to set the boolean `SharedPreference`

```
public static final void setBoolPreference(Context base, String prefName,
        String key, boolean value) {

    SharedPreferences userPref = base.getSharedPreferences(prefName,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

This is how i am getting the `SharedPreference`

```
public static final boolean getBoolPreference(Context base,
        String prefName, String key) {

    SharedPreferences usePref = base.getSharedPreferences(prefName,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean value = usePref.getBoolean(key, false);
    return value;
}
```

and this is the code where i need to use the `sharedpreference` saved state to play sound or not

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.stronghold);

    if (PrefrencesClass.getBoolPreference(context, Constants.APPSPREF,
            Constants.FIRSTTIME) == false) {
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
```

Boolean state is not saving Please Help

Comment: Can you show `setBoolPreferences` method?

Comment: oh sorry Mistakenly posted code of `sharedIntPreference` refresh for correct one @PrerakSola

Comment: You are using different keys. For mute it is `Constants.FIRSTTIME` and for volume it is `Constants.APPSPREF`

Comment: look again to setBoolPreference Method Constant.APPSPREF is String value and Actual key is Constants.FIRSTTIME and it is same in both @PrerakSola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void saveBooleanToSharedPref(Context context, String key, boolean value){

        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();

}//saveBooleanToSharedPref


public static boolean getBooleanBySharedPref(Context context, String key){

        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean value = settings.getBoolean(key, true);

        return value;

}//getStringBySharedPref
```

Your set is wrong, because you use putInt method.

Comment: first it was mistake that i write putInt Method
But  I tried your code but still not saving
@br00

Comment: can you post the rest of your code? Maybe the problem could be your variable "check". Are you sure that you enter in the if condition? Or maybe the problem could be your variable Constants.FIRSTTIME..

Comment: i declared this variable above on `onCreate` Method `boolean check = false;`
and this is the only place is use this variable on `volume` click you can check above for the code of volume onclick
 @br00

Comment: I solve the problem your answer was not exactly what i want but its close to my answer so choosing this one as selected answer and yet shared preference of your code is working totally fine .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to say:

```
volume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            check = !check  // avoids if statements, same below

            SharedPreferences prefsget =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefset = prefsget.edit();
            prefset.putBoolean(yourBoolVar, !prefsget.getBoolean(yourBoolVar, false));
            prefset.commit();
    }
});
```

You can still put an if statement for setting image background. But the what I have above should cut down on a lot of your code. Remember to replace the activity I typed above with your own activity and also for the boolean variable too.